# not able to connect to mysql running on amazon ec2 instance

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, amazon-ec2

I'm running mysql on ec2 instance. I can connect to this db by doing an SSH to that instance and then connecting to mysql server on command line. But when I try connecting to it via mysql JDBC I get connection timeout error. I have an RDS instance also that has mysql to which I can connect through mysql JDBC. What might be the issue?

Comment: Are the ports open? Have you tried turning iptables off to test? (don't leave it off!) There may also be other EC2 configuration to open ports, I'm not certain. Is MySQL listening on the right IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to the security settings of the ec2 instance and please open the port number 3306, you should able to connect to the mysql

Comment: I'll try this. I tried to connect to RDS instance through JDBC from my local laptop again and it failed. Also read that to connect to any RDS instance, I need to connect through EC2. I dont know how it worked from my laptop once or twice and stopped working thereafter. Is there any way I can connect to RDS from my laptop?